# How to draw an ELLIPSE on C++ MFC using D2D and the class CD2DEllipse

Tags: c++, mfc, direct2d

I need draw an ELLIPSE on C++ MFC using D2D and the class CD2DEllipse,
I want that if I change the size of the window, the ellipse change size too.

I want that the pointer of the object see the class...and so I declare it to the header:

```
//hpp
class CmyclassView : public CView
{
...
CD2DEllipse* pE;
...
}
```

case A:

I have to initialize the ellipse object CD2DEllipse every time
that I resize the view...WM_PAINT -> OnDraw2D ... but I put the ellipse
on the heap because of "new"...and where go the previous ellipse...

If I close the application the d_str have to call "delete pE; " ?

```
// cpp
afx_msg LRESULT CDXALGOView::OnDraw2D(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
C_pRT = (CHwndRenderTarget*)lParam;
ASSERT_VALID(C_pRT);
pE = new CD2DEllipse(D2D1::Ellipse(xyC,r,r));  <<-------
return TRUE;
}
```

case B:
or is best create the object only one time in the constructor, the update
the parameters on the ondraw, and when I close cthe application I delete
the object
c_str

```
{
 pE = new CD2DEllipse(D2D1::Ellipse(xyC,r,r));
}
afx_msg LRESULT CDXALGOView::OnDraw2D(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
 C_pRT = (CHwndRenderTarget*)lParam;
 ASSERT_VALID(C_pRT);
 pE.point = xyC;  <<-------
 pE.radiusX = r;
 pE.radiusY = r;
 return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create the object on the stack, when you need it:

```
C_pRT->DrawEllipse( CD2DEllipse(D2D1::Ellipse(xyC, r, r)), someBrush, lineWidth );
```

You may break up that statement for better readability:

```
CD2DEllipse ellipse( D2D1::Ellipse(xyC, r, r) ); 
C_pRT->DrawEllipse( ellipse, someBrush, lineWidth );
```

In general, there is rarely a need for `new` in modern C++. Most of the times, you just create objects on the stack and let their destructors do the cleanup automatically. If you actually have to allocate something on the heap, use one of the [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory) provided by the standard library. These take care of calling `delete` automatically.

Comment: I have a lot of Ellipse, Rectangle and other...so I thought that it could be better save the pointer on the class...so every time when I change the size of the win...I can modify only the dimension...or do you think that is less expensive create all every time? other...I receive lot of data from a LAN so often I need redraw only single part of the win...and if I have class pointers it's easy...I think...or not?

Comment: Other problem is the Text Format...for change the character size I have to create the format every time it seems...correct? There is a better way for change the size of characters…? thank u very much for your answer

Comment: @GiPag These are just wrapper classes, very cheap to create on the stack all the time. When you have a pointer, there is an indirection, which is more expensive. I don't know about text format, better you post a new question.

Comment: @GiPag: Heap allocations are insanely expensive. In the time it takes to allocate a single object on the heap, you can probably instantiate hundreds of objects on the stack. Plus, pointers are expensive, too. They trash cache locality. If you want to improve performance, you need to measure performance first.